# Questions regarding Monero wallet keys file, RPC transfer method, fee estimate and account index

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I have following questions regarding Monero wallets.

Using the Monero GUI and CLI wallet, I have created a wallet which generates three files in my file storage. One is a text file, which has the address of my wallet, and another file with .keys extention.

My questions:

1. What format are the values in the .keys file? I.e. Hex/Base58 or something else?
2. If I create a new, second wallet, does it have one account at index 0 and default address at 0 index too?
3. As per the API documentation, [query_key](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#query_key) will return either the private view key or mnemonic seed. If I want to execute the transfer method, why don't I need the private spend key in the parameters object? Or do I have to do this process using the sign transaction method separately and then call transfer?
4. How do I estimate fees before sending a transaction?
5. If I move forward with the concept I've explained in Q2, then should I make a transfer and pass 0 as `account_index`? Which wallet will be choosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The keys file is binary data. It's actually a json string that is encrypted with your wallet password.
2. Whenever you create a new wallet, it always starts with a single account (account index 0), with a single main address (subaddress index 0).
3. The wallet RPC only operates with one wallet at a time, so once you have opened a wallet, the keys are loaded and you do not need to specify any key to perform a transfer. `query_key` is used for other purposes, not transfers.
4. Call [transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) with `do_not_relay:true` and `get_tx_metadata:true`. This will respond with the fee in the result object and the tx data you can then use with the [relay_tx](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#relay_tx) method.
5. The wallet that gets used is the one you started the monero-wallet-rpc with or the wallet 
   file you opened with [open_wallet](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#open_wallet). Specifying `account_index:0` when doing a transfer, instructs the transfer to send from the first (main) account of the currently opened wallet.

Comment: OK, Thank you for the clear answer, The main thing about wallet is, if we are working with monero wallet rpc, at a time only one wallet will be used for further processes, i.e., transfer. am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes. Just like the GUI or CLI. You work with one wallet at a time. To use another wallet, you close the current and open the other.